# Hypothesis testing, two equivalent definitions, mean value, unclear equivalence

Tags: probability, expectation, means, hypothesis-testing, parameter-estimation

We consider two definitions of the **power function** which equivalence is unclear to me.

(1) The power function of a test, denoted by $Q(\theta)$ is the probability of rejecting null hypothesis $H_0$ when $\theta\in \Theta$ is the true parameter
value. The power function is then given by
$$Q(\theta)=P_\theta(\cal R).$$

We have obviously here $Q(\theta_0)=\alpha$ and $Q(\theta_1)=1-\beta$
where $\alpha$ is the I type error and $\beta$ is the II type error.

(2) A function $\psi(.):\cal X^n\to [0,1]$ is called the critical function
where $\psi(\mathbb{x})$ stands for the probability with which the null hypothesis $H_0$ is rejected when the data $\mathbb{X}=\mathbb{x}$ has been
observed, $\mathbb{x}\in \cal X^n$.

**Why** now, we can rewrite the power function defined in (1) as follows

$$Q(\theta)=E_\theta\{\psi(\mathbb{X)}\}$$ for $\theta\in \Theta$ ?
Where comes the expected value under the true $\theta$ from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P_\theta(\text{reject}) = E_\theta[1_{\text{reject}}] = E_\theta[E_\theta[1_{\text{reject}} \mid X]] = E_\theta[\psi(X)].$$

Comment: The answer is too much brief for me. Could you please explain the three equalities?

Comment: @user122424 For an event $A$, the indicator random variable $1_A$ is $1$ if $A$ occurs, and $0$ otherwise. Then $P(A)=E[1_A]$. This explains the first and last equalities. The middle equality is [tower rule / law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: When we have shown the first and third equality, why do we include the middle one at all?

Comment: @user122424 The definition of $\psi$ involves $X$.